# Invoking a method from a different class - help needed with constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Thanks for your patience - I'm starting my post all over again and going ahead and putting up everything I have. It's hard for me to explain what advice I need because I don't quite understand what's wrong. If anyone can take a look, that would be wonderful. The biggest problem I am having is with the CHECK BALANCE button - namely that when clicking the button, the getBalance() does not retrieve the proper data and the JOptionPane comes up as saying "The amount of your checks total in US is $0.00", regardless of whether I tried to "deposit" money or not.

TRAVELCHECK CLASS

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TravelCheck extends JFrame {
private static final int WIDTH = 400, HEIGHT = 300;
ButtonHandler bHandler = new ButtonHandler(); 
JLabel cash = new JLabel("Cash Your Check", SwingConstants.CENTER);
JLabel click = new JLabel("Click the Button that matches your currency type", SwingConstants.CENTER);

JButton pesoB = new JButton(TravelString.PESO_S);
JButton francB = new JButton(TravelString.FRANC_S);
JButton euroB = new JButton(TravelString.EURO_S);
JButton usdB = new JButton(TravelString.US_S);
JButton checkB = new JButton(TravelString.CHECK_S);
JButton exitB = new JButton(TravelString.EXIT_S);

public TravelCheck() {
Container pane = getContentPane();
pane.add(cash);
pane.add(click);
pane.add(pesoB);
pane.add(francB);
pane.add(usdB);
pane.add(checkB);
pane.add(exitB);

pesoB.addActionListener(bHandler);
francB.addActionListener(bHandler);
euroB.addActionListener(bHandler);
usdB.addActionListener(bHandler);
checkB.addActionListener(bHandler);
exitB.addActionListener(bHandler);

setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
setTitle("Check Machine");
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); }

public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

Checks mexican = new Checks(TravelString.PESO_S);
Checks swiss = new Checks(TravelString.FRANC_S);
Checks european = new Checks(TravelString.EURO_S);
Checks us = new Checks(TravelString.US_S);

if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.EXIT_S))
    System.exit(0);
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.PESO_S))
    transaction(mexican);
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.FRANC_S))
transaction(swiss);
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.EURO_S))
    transaction(european);
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.US_S))
    transaction(us);
else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.CHECK_S)) {

//this is where I'm having the problem, I think
String str;
Checks test = new Checks("hello");
double temp = test.getBalance();
str = String.format("The amount of your checks total in US is $%.2f", temp);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "Traveler's check balance", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}

public void transaction(Checks C) {
int temp = intPrompt(C);
if (temp == 1)
if (C.getFace() == 0) {
String denomS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the denomination of checks that you want.");
int denomination = Integer.parseInt(denomS);

String numberS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of checks that you want");
int number = Integer.parseInt(numberS);
C.deposit(number, denomination); }

else {
int denomination = C.getFace();
String numS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of checks that you want");
int number = Integer.parseInt(numS);
C.deposit(number, denomination); }

//else if...
//The code keeps on going for other options (withdrawal and quit), but the above is the most relevant.

public int intPrompt(Checks C) {
String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("For the country of " + C.getCountry() + " you have " + C.getNumber() + " checks with face value denomination of $" + C.getFace() + "\nPlease enter:\n1 - for a deposit\n2 - for a withdrawal\n3 - to quit");
int choiceI = Integer.parseInt(choice);
return choiceI; } }
public static void main(Strin[] args) {
TravelCheck tc = new TravelCheck(); } }
```

FOR CHECKS CLASS

```
public class Checks {
private static final double
PESO = 2.0, FRANC = 3.0, EURO = 4.0;
private int numberOfChecks;
private int faceAmount;
private String country;
private static double balance;

public Checks (String s) {
numberOfChecks = 0;
faceAmount = 0;
balance = 0.0;
if (s.equals(TravelString.PESO S) || s.equals(TravelString.FRANC S) || s.equals(TravelString.EURO S) || s.equals(TravelString.US S))
country = s;
else {
country = TravelString.US S;
System.err.println("ERROR: Bad Checks"); }}

public int getNumber() {
return numberOfChecks; }
public String getCountry() {
return country; }
public int getFace() {
return faceAmount; }
public double getBalance() {
return balance; }

public void deposit(int number, int denomination) {
if (number > 0 && denomination > 0 ) {
if (faceAmount == 0) {
faceAmount = denomination;
numberOfChecks = number;
balance += faceAmount * number * conversion(); }
else if (faceAmount == denomination) {
numberOfChecks += number;
balance += faceAmount * number * conversion(); }
else 
System.err.println("### Non-existent denomination error in deposit() ###"); }
else
System.err.println("### Non-positive parameter error in deposit() ###"); }

public void withdrawal(int number) {
if (number < 0) // bad invocation scenarios
System.err.println("### Negative parameter error in withdrawal() ###");
else if (balance < number * faceAmount * conversion())
System.err.println("### Overdraw error in withdrawal() ###");
else {
numberOfChecks -= number;
balance -= faceAmount * number * conversion();
if (numberOfChecks == 0)
faceAmount = 0; } }

private double conversion() { 
// converts monetary amounts to US Dollars
double retval = 0.0;
if (country.equals(TravelString.US S))
retval = 1.0;
else if (country.equals(TravelString.PESO S))
retval = 1.0/PESO;
else if (country.equals(TravelString.FRANC S))
retval = 1.0/FRANC;
else if (country.equals(TravelString.EURO S))
retval = 1.0/EURO;
return retval; }
```

TRAVEL STRING CLASS

```
public class TravelString {
public static final String
PESO_S = "Mexican peso" ,
FRANC_S = "Swiss franc" ,
EURO_S = "Euro dollar" ,
US_S = "US dollar" ,
CHECK_S = "Check Balance" ,
EXIT_S = "Exit"; }
```

Thank you!

Comment: So, what is the constructor argument `s` used for, in the `Sums` constructor?  What value do you WANT to have here, when your `Sums` object is constructed?

Comment: Show us the full constructor for `Sums`

Comment: Well, you definitely need to add a string argument when using `new Sums`.  As for why the program doesn't run correctly when you do, we don't have nearly enough information.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to make a call to the constructor `Sums()`, but you have only declared `Sums(String s)`.
Add the String to your method call and it should work

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

You can either write a default constructor for `Sums`, or send a `String` argument to the constructor.

---

A default constructor would look like this (in the `Sums` class):

```
public Sums() {
    //do any initialization
}
```

---

Or to send a `String` to the constructor, change this:

```
Sums temp = new Sums();
```

You need to send it a `String` argument, such as this:

```
Sums temp = new Sums("Hello World");
```

Or some string that makes sense for initializing this object.

I'd have to see the actual `public Sums(String s)` code to even make a guess at what would make sense here.

---

And as has been commented on the original question, to determine why your program isn't running "correctly", we'll need a lot more information, starting with what you mean by "isn't running correctly", and including more info from the `Sums` class.

Answer (score 0):

The message is self-explanatory you don't have a constructor with no arguments.

A possible solution is modifying your `Sum` class adding a no-args constructor.

```
public class Sums {

//Add default constructor
public Sums(){

}

public Sums (String s)
{
...
}
public double getTotal() {
return total; 
}
}
```

Another possible solution, change your client code passing a String as parameter.`

```
Sums temp = new Sums("here put the string!!");
double number = temp.getTotal();
```